# Create first-class object all of it's instance attributes are readonly like slice?

Tags: python, python-2.7, metaclass, readonly-attribute

My question is how to create a class like `slice`?

`slice` (built-in type) doesn't have a `__dict__` attribute
even that the `metaclass` of this `slice` is `type`.

And it is not using `__slots__`, and **all it's attribute are readonly** and it's not overriding
`__setattr__` (this i'm not sure about it but look at my code and see if I'm right).

Check this code:

```
# how slice is removing the __dict__ from the class object
# and the metaclass is type!!

class sliceS(object):
    pass

class sliceS0(object):

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        pass

# this means that both have the same
# metaclass type.
print type(slice) == type(sliceS) # prints True

# from what i understand the metaclass is the one
# that is responsible for making the class object
sliceS2 = type('sliceS2', (object,), {})
# witch is the same
# sliceS2 = type.__new__(type, 'sliceS2', (object,), {})
print type(sliceS2) # prints type

# but when i check the list of attribute using dir
print '__dict__' in dir(slice)  # prints False
print '__dict__' in dir(sliceS) # prints True

# now when i try to set an attribute on slice
obj_slice = slice(10)
# there is no __dict__  here
print '__dict__' in dir(obj_slice) # prints False
obj_sliceS = sliceS()
try:
    obj_slice.x = 1
except AttributeError as e:
    # you get AttributeError
    # mean you cannot add new properties
    print "'slice' object has no attribute 'x'"

obj_sliceS.x = 1 # Ok: x is added to __dict__ of obj_sliceS
print 'x' in obj_sliceS.__dict__ # prints True

# and slice is not using __slots__ because as you see it's not here
print '__slots__' in dir(slice) # print False

# and this why i'm saying it's not overriding the __settattr__
print id(obj_slice.__setattr__) == id(obj_sliceS.__setattr__) # True: it's the same object
obj_sliceS0 = sliceS0()
print id(obj_slice.__setattr__) == id(obj_sliceS0.__setattr__) # False: it's the same object

# so slice have only start, stop, step and are all readonly attribute and it's not overriding the __setattr__
# what technique it's using?!!!!
```

**How to make this kind of first-class object all of it's attributes are readonly and you cannot
add new attributes.**

Comment: ... what do you mean by "first-class object"?

Comment: I suppose you mean *built-in* type.

Comment: but it's possible to create a class that have the same behavior

Comment: If you mean by not overriding `setattr` or using `__slots__`? Write a C-extension. Or use `property` or some other descriptor, without implementing `__set__`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thank you for comment i edited my question to remove the conflict. the question is how can i create a class that behave like the slice

Comment: So we cannot do something like this in pure python

Comment: you could use a descriptor like `property` in combinations with `__slots__`

Comment: if you have an idea post as an answer if it doesn't require to much codes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169415/discussion-between-cherif-and-juanpa-arrivillaga).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is that Python's built-in `slice` class is programmed in C. And when you code using the C-Python API you can code the equivalent of attributes accessible with the `__slots__` without using any mechanisms visible from the Python side. (You can even have 'real' private attributes, which are virtually impossible with Python only code).

The mechanism used for Python code to be able to prevent a `__dict__` for a class' instances and subsequent "any attribute can be set" is the `__slots__` exactly the attribute. 
However, unlike magic dunder methods that have to be present when the class is actually used, the information on `__slots__` is used when the class is created, and only then.  So, if what concerns you is to have a visible `__slots__` in your final class, you can just remove it from the class before exposing it:

```
In [8]: class A:
   ...:     __slots__ = "b"
   ...:     

In [9]: del A.__slots__

In [10]: a = A()

In [11]: a.b = 5

In [12]: a.c = 5
------------------------
AttributeError   
...

In [13]: A.__slots__
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-68a69c802e74> in <module>()
----> 1 A.__slots__

AttributeError: type object 'A' has no attribute '__slots__'
```

If you won't like a `del MyClass.__slots__` line to be visible wherever you declare a class, it is a one-line class decorator:

```
def slotless(cls):
   del cls.__slots__
   return cls

@slotless
class MyClass:
   __slots__ = "x y".split()
```

Or, you could use a metaclass to auto-create, and auto-destroy the Python visible `__slots__`, so that you could declare your descriptors and attributes in the class body, and have the class protected against extra attributes:

```
class AttrOnly(type):
   def __new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace, **kw):
        namespace["__slots__"] = list(namespace.keys())  # not sure if "list(" is needed
        cls = super().__new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace, **kw)
        del cls.__slots__
        return cls

class MyClass(metaclass=AttrOnly):
    x = int
    y = int
```

If you want pure Python readonly attributes which does not have a visible counterpart in the instance itself (like a `._x` which is used by a `property` descriptor to keep the value of a `x` attribute), the straightforward way is to customize `__setattr__` . Another approach is to have your metaclass to auto-add a read-only property for each attribute on the class creation stage. The metaclass bellow does that and uses the `__slots__` class attribute to create the desired descriptors:

```
class ReadOnlyAttrs(type):
    def __new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace, **kw):
        def get_setter(attr):
            def setter(self, value):
                if getattr(self, "_initialized", False): 
                    raise ValueError("Can't set "  + attr)
                setattr(self, "_" + attr, value)
            return setter

        slots = namespace.get("__slots__", [])
        slots.append("initialized")
        def __new__(cls, *args, **kw):
            self = object.__new__(cls)  # for production code that could have an arbitrary hierarchy, this needs to be done more carefully
            for attr, value in kw.items():
                setattr(self, attr, value)
            self.initialized = True
            return self

        namespace["__new__"] = __new__
        real_slots = []
        for attr in slots:
            real_slots.append("_" + attr)
            namespace[attr] = property(
                (lambda attr: lambda self: getattr(self, "_" + attr))(attr), # Getter. Extra lambda needed to create an extra closure containing each attr
                get_setter(attr)
            )
        namespace["__slots__"] = real_slots
        cls = super().__new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace, **kw)
        del cls.__slots__
        return cls
```

Have in mind you can also customize the class' `__dir__` method so that `_x` shadow attributes would not be seen, if you want to.

Comment: It actually does nothing, just let `__slots__` not visibble. I added it because the "non-existence" of `__slots__` in the created class is a concern in the question.

Comment: Sorry - just now I saw you have the "python 2.7" tag there. The only thng that should change above however is how to make use of the metaclass, (and te metaclass "kw"  attributes will be useless, I'd guess) ; Anyway, it makes little sense to research advanced Python features in python 2 these day's, I'd suggest you to update to 3.6 .

Comment: @jsbueno i didn't know that i can remove the __slots__ from the calss object so basically if the class object don't have a __dict__ attribute and no subclass you cannot add new attribute to it. i'm i right ?

Comment: @jsbueno sill one thing missing here how to make this attribute readonly. i don't think there is a way for this without overriding the `__setattr__`